# Apscheduler calling function too quickly

Tags: python, django, apscheduler

Here is my scheduler.py file:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from django_apscheduler.jobstores import DjangoJobStore, register_events
from django.utils import timezone
from django_apscheduler.models import DjangoJobExecution
import sys

# This is the function you want to schedule - add as many as you want and then register them in the start() function below
def hello():
    print("Hello")


def start():
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_jobstore(DjangoJobStore(), "default")
    # run this job every 10 seconds
    scheduler.add_job(hello, 'interval', seconds=10, jobstore='default')
    register_events(scheduler)
    scheduler.start()
    print("Scheduler started...", file=sys.stdout)
```

My Django app runs fine on localhost. I'm simply attempting to print 'hello' every 10 seconds in the terminal, but it sometimes prints like 3 or 4 at a time. Why is this? This was just a base template to help understand apscheduler.

Comment: How are you calling the start function and how are you ruining your app? Is it possible you have multiple workers each running an instance of your scheduler?

Answer (score 1):

The primary reason this might be happening is if you are running your development server without the `--noreload` flag set, which will cause the scheduler to be called twice (sometimes more).

When you run your server in development, try it like:

```
python manage.py runserver localhost:8000 --noreload
```

And see what happens. If it still keeps happening, it may be that the interval is too close together so by the time your system gets around to it, another version is still being called (even though it is a very short function). Django stores all pending, overdue, and run jobs in the database, so it has to store a record for the job after each transaction. Try expanding the interval and see what happens.

If neither of those things work, please post the rest of the code you are using and I will update my answer with other options. I've had a similar issue in the past, but it was solved with the `--noreload` option being set. When you run it in production behind a regular web server with `DEBUG=False`, then it should resolve itself as well.